# Get Absolute Path of Resource directory without referring to any file within it - Scala?

Tags: scala

I am from Java background and new to Scala. I tried searching for ways to find the resource directory absolute path without referring to any file within it, but answers were of referring to a file present within resources folder.

I tried below ways but got exception (`java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2`).

```
var resourceDirectory: java.nio.file.Path = null;
resourceDirectory = Paths.get(getClass.getResource(".").getPath)
resourceDirectory = Paths.get(getClass.getResource("/").getPath)
resourceDirectory = Paths.get(getClass.getResource("./").getPath)
```

How to get the Absolute path of resources directory without referring to any files it contains?

Comment: Why do you want the resources directory full path? That seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: This resourceDirectory value is used in other places of code to refer to resource path. So this variable is kind of set as global variable

Comment: Again, why do you need that? There is no sense in requiring the resources directory. It is not even a directory.

Comment: Agree. I changed my code to refer to resource file path. Thanks for taking time to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for this because resources are usually stored in a jar file along with the application's class files. In this very common case you can't access the resource directory because there isn't one.